# Ajax code not working in safari and firefox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, safari, mozilla

Ajax code for language switching from database is not working in safari and Firefox, but its perfectly working on chrome and edge. Safari doesn't respond to ajax call but in firefox it only work after a lot of attempts to change language.

**My code is**

```
<?php

session_start();
if($_SESSION)
{
$bid=$_SESSION['latest'];
}
else
{
$bid=1;
}

?>

<select name="sources" id="language_id" onclick="" onchange="location.reload();langchange();">
<?php
$language = mysqli_query($link, "select * from language_reference");
while ($lang = mysqli_fetch_array($language)) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $lang['lang_id']; ?>"
    <?php
   if($lang['lang_id']==$bid)
   {
       echo 'selected="selected"' ;
   }
   ?>
    ><?php echo $lang['lang_name']; ?>
    </option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>


<div class="row" >
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM category AS c INNER JOIN category_language AS cl ON c.id=cl.category_id where parent_id IS NULL && lang_id='1' ");
$var = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 hvr-shrink" style="position: relative; margin-top: 50px;">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <div>
         <img src="admin/uploads/category/<?php echo $row['cat_home_image']; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block" width="50px" />
         <p class="category-caption" style="padding-top: 20px; text-align: center;" id="cat_desc<?php echo $var; ?>"></p>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<?php
$var++;
}
?>
```

**ajax script**

```
<script>
 function langchange() {
 var language_id = $('#language_id').val();
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajax_lang_change.php",
     data: "id=" + language_id,
     success: function (value)
     {
        var data = value.split("|_,_|");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#cat_desc" + i).html(data[i]);
        }
     }
 });

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_get_session.php",
    data: "bid=" + language_id,
    success: function (value) {
     var data = value;
    }
 });
 }
 $(window).ready(function () {
    langchange()
 });

</script>
```

**php script to get data from db**

**ajax_lang_change.php**

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM category AS c INNER JOIN category_language AS cl ON c.id=cl.category_id where parent_id IS NULL && lang_id='$id'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['category_description']."|_,_|";
}

?>
```

ajax_get_session.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
session_start();

$bid = $_POST['bid'];

$_SESSION['latest']=$bid;

if(isset($_SESSION['latest']))
{
  echo 'success';
}
else
{
  echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

is there anyway to solve this problem? should I have to write ajax script for various browsers?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You shouldn't need to have different ajax calls per browser. What actually happens when _"it's not working"_? Have you checked the browsers debug console for errors? Have you checked the browsers debug network tab to see if the request get's made or what the response of the request is? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: I had same issue before 2 years but after adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to head. Thats working perfect.

Comment: @RaviShrimali - So what was the actual solution? Including a new version of jQuery or didn't you use jQuery at all before that?

Comment: I think the session set is not working in safari... but its working in other browsers

Comment: How are you debugging your code? This is important because (1) remove the prefix `I think` from your answers and (2) provides information more useful than `is not working`.